# Lag in Edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

There is a noticable lag when ever I edit something in edit mode such as moving, rotating, scaling edges/verteces, or any addjustments in edit mode. I work on one and simple model (I am begginer)

I have [image]decent laptop performace (Triton 300, GTX 1650 I7-9500)

Any fix/adjustment for better performance or better, eliminate lag entirely?

Comment: By any chance, do you have Auto Depth enabled in User Prefs? If so, try to disable it and see if it persists.

Comment: I checked and it was already disabled. Tried it both ways, didn't make difference @michaelh

Comment: You can try to disable the Subdivision Surface Modifier.

Comment: I disabled the sub. modifier and it noticable improved the editing. Is than an issue with the GPU? @michaelh

Comment: What level did you have it set at?

Comment: at level 2 @batFINGER

Comment: The model you have shouldn't be too slow at Level 2 (which is why it wasn't my first suggestion) - The reason for the slowdown is hard to tell at this point. Make sure you're on the latest GPU drivers. Also, try again with factory settings. - If it runs smooth, you can enable any customization you have one by one and see if it breaks performance at some point. Or you can turn off Anti-Aliasing in the Viewport settings (user prefs).

Comment: Found the issue! I was triyng to do edge bevels using vertex group attached to a bevel modifier instead of by making close loop cuts close to the edge. Now that I deleted the bevel modifier, every thing works smooth!